# Unable to access our own cookies within salesforce Iframe

Tags: lightning-experience, iframe, call-center

I have an external webphone application within salesforce lightning which is loaded via Call Center. Users need to login through credentials. It was working before and any issues. Now, in the backend side the cookies was set and used for authentication but it failed when it is running inside salesforce. I log the cookie and it is null but when the webphone application is loaded outside of salesforce, the cookies are available and not null. I assume that something has changed within salesforce but I'm accessing our cookies not salesforce. Does salesforce parent window blocks all cookies access if third party Iframe tried to access cookies even if the cookie is not from salesforce?

so basically my application is in IFrame within salesforce, so does my cookie define as third party? but I'm setting and getting the cookie within the iframe in server side but somehow I can't retrieve these cookies but when I am in the same domain I can retrieve the cookies with no issues because it became first party. the issue is I'm not modifying/getting the cookies of salesforce but my own. I hope you understand my point and can help me with this.

If anyone have similar issues please let me know. I've been digging for past days and can't figure out.

Thank you.

Comment: Your cookie is first party if you are setting and reading the cookie in same domain else for a different domain it is a third party cookie and browsers are increasingly enforcing blocking read of a third party cookie. So check the domain from which you are setting and reading cookies. Maybe you can add more details to your questions. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/09/alternatives-to-cookies-for-third-party-ui-integrations.html

Comment: so basically my application is in IFrame within salesforce, so does my cookie define as third party? but I'm setting and getting the cookie within the iframe in server side but somehow I can't retrieve these cookies but when I am in the same domain I can retrieve the cookies with no issues because it became first party. the issue is I'm not modifying/getting the cookies of salesforce but my own.

Comment: Then its not the case of third party cookies definitely. I belive you cookie should have samesite and secure attribute defined. Can you confirm if you browser generates a warning in console regarding Samesite attribute while loading the iframe

Comment: I just check the request and its cookies. so it looks like the request cookies has cookies with yellow highlights that says about samesite attribute so does it mean that when I do that request I need to add the samesite attribute tom make it work? so basically when I do a request from iframe I'm still doing a request like I'm doing it in parent domain? I thought that when I do the request I am in context of the iframe.